# OpenCV padded Mat, use with VideoWriter

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have an image represented using a 2D array of 3 byte color values (OpenCV type `CV_8UC3`). The array is not densely packed, but instead elements are aligned on a 4 byte boundary, i.e. there is 1 byte of padding.

So the array is of the format

```
RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_RGB_...
```

I want to access this data using OpenCV, without making a new copy of it. But OpenCV `Mat` of type `CV_8UC3` is packed by default, so I create the `Mat` with explicit strides/steps, using

```
cv::Mat mat(
    2,
    sizes, // = (1080, 1920)
    CV_8UC3,
    reinterpret_cast<void*>(data),
    steps // = (7680, 4)
);
```

`data` is a pointer to a `rgb_color` array, defined by

```
struct alignas(4) rgb_color { std::uint8_t r, g, b; };
```

However using this `mat` with `cv::VideoWriter` still produces incorrect results, and it seems that `VideoWriter` ignores the strides of the `Mat`.

Is it possible to use `VideoWriter` and other OpenCV functionality with matrices of this type?

Comment: Is  CV_8UC4 (RGBA model) suitable?

Comment: No, because the padded byte (A channel) should be ignored. Also the code is part of a generic framework, so it should also work for other strides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VideoWriter is whimsical thing, so I won't surprised if it just copies data as simple RGB.

Excerpt from sources - FFMPEG proxy function for `writeframe`:

```
   return icvWriteFrame_FFMPEG_p(ffmpegWriter, (const uchar*)image->imageData,
        image->widthStep, image->width, image->height, image->nChannels, image->origin) !=0;
```

It uses line step padding (widthStep), but ignores per-element padding. I think that some similar code is for other AVI-writing approaches (vfw, dx, qt etc - lazy to check).

Note that per-element padding is poorly documented (just mentioned in `steps` description), so I suspect it's support might be omitted in some functions.

Comment: Exactly. I treat the I/O functionality in OCV as just convenience code to get some prototypes running quickly, not something for production use. Even the interface of VideoWriter screams single purpose -- write some common Mat formats to a file. At least the CUDA implementation provides callbacks for some flexibility.